# highlight 'comm' command output

Tags: arrays, regex, linux, bash, scripting

Given the output below (simplified) extracted from the comparison of two `curl -I` commands saved in two different files, I am looking for the best approach to highlight the following scenarios in a script:

1. this header exists only in file1.txt but this one does not
2. this one exists in both cases but the values are different

I was thinking about assigning green color to column 3, orange color if the header is found both in column 1 and column 2 and no color if the header is found only either in column 1 or column 2... I am also open to suggestions different from colors or by processing file1.txt and file2.txt with other options than `comm` command or assigning the values into associative arrays and compare them via regular expressions.

```
root# comm <(sort file1.txt | tr '.' ',') <(sort file2.txt | tr '.' ',')

Accept-Ranges: none
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
    Cache-Control: public, max-age=14400
    CF-Cache-Status: HIT
        HTTP/1,1 200 OK
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply install [grc/grcat](https://github.com/garabik/grc), which is a generic colourizer, and create a config for comm